# Apache 2.22 + php 5.40 + Symfony2 Frameowrk = Apache Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, symfony

I have installed the new Symfony 2.1 framework on my local server

when i run `http://www.myhost.com/app_dev.php`

i get on my browser

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

and when i checkout my /var/log/apache2/error.log file, i see

```
[Tue Apr 24 12:03:43 2012] [notice] seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
[Tue Apr 24 12:03:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.0-3~precise+4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 24 12:03:58 2012] [notice] child pid 3016 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Apr 24 12:03:59 2012] [notice] child pid 3014 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Apr 24 12:04:00 2012] [notice] child pid 3025 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Apr 24 12:04:01 2012] [notice] child pid 3013 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Apr 24 12:04:24 2012] [notice] child pid 3012 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

how can i debug, or better solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the reason why PHP makes an httpd segfault (without leaving a core dump, I suppose) is a faulty extension in PHP, or a combination of two incompatible ones.

Examples are:

- APC + XCache (or, in general two accelerators)
- suhosin + xdebug

Comment: thanks, i figured out it has to do with my apc, when i enable it, it breaks again....here are my configs  extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/apc.so
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 50M

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to use apc with your configuration then ?