# Symfony 2: session_start causes ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: session, symfony

We just moved our Symfony2.3 project to another server and now we encounter the following problem:

The routes `/login` and `_wdt/9d5405` result in a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in Google Chrome (and all other browsers showing their specific error messages). The error occurs in both, prod and dev environment.

I tracked down the issue from my loginAction

```
/**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @Route("/login/{redirect}", name="login_redirect")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction($redirect = '')
    {
        if ($this->getUser())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('crea_frontend_index'));
        }

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))
        {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
               SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        $redirect = urldecode($redirect);

        return array(
           'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME), // last username entered by the user
           'redirect' => $redirect,
           'error' => $error,
        );
    }
```

This line produces the error:

```
$error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
```

And I tracked it down to

```
Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
```

and there in line 148 `if (!session_start()) {`.

So it turnes out that session_start at this point produces the error but when I add a `session_start();` to app.php and comment everything else it works.

Now I am completely puzzled on how to fix this. Any ideas on how to solve this or just how to further debug would be very appriciated.

- PHP 5.4.20
- No errors in logfiles

**UPDATE**

The error seems to be somehow related to these bug discussions:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/424789
https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276583

**UPDATE**

**Solved:** The Problem was the PHP Version 5.4.20. We tested 5.3.17 and 5.5.9. Both function well. Except 5.4.20. But I still want to know what exaclty causes this error. This could then result in a Symfony fix to deal with this version.

Comment: What version of PHP and APC are you using? No errors in the log files (PHP/Webserver/symfony)?

Comment: @nifr I added the php version and I am still trying to find out the apc version. None of the logfiles contains any errors.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows?

Comment: linux openSuse 13.1 64bit, and i just found out the apc version, it is 3.1.15-dev

Comment: `phpversion('apc')` will output the APC version.

Comment: try downgrading to APC 3.1.13-beta - PHP 5.4 support was introduced in **[3.1.10](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC/3.1.10)**. Or consider updating to `PHP 5.5.x` with `ZendOpcache` + `APCu`.

Comment: ok I am sorry for this misleading information but it doesn't seem to be related to apc. I turned it off and the error still occurs.

Comment: are you sure you turned it off (not only removed the line from configuration)? you have to either restart your `php-fpm` service or (if you're using php as a module) apache webserver afterwards .

Comment: I set `apc.enabled=0` and restarted apache. Also the apc.php, which ships with apc, prints out `No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.` So yes I am quite sure.

Comment: did you try disabling the extension completely by removing/commenting apc's `extension=apc.so` directive yet?

Comment: @nifr We now now that apc is not crucial. While testing the different php versions it was always off.

Comment: I'm 95% sure it was apc *in combination* with php **5.4.x**. you didn't completely disable/unload the extension as i told you and that's why you still experienced the error.Just google for "[php 5.4 err_empty_reponse](https://www.google.de/search?q=php+5.4+err_empty_response+apc)". **This is a well known bug.** You can find various bug reports about it i.e. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/-ChJqjeOIRg), [here](http://groundless.org/php-apc-bug), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10295828/1832745) and **[here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1287)**, ...

Comment: Hm... ok maybe your right. I am quite sure we disabled it completely but the problem really seems to be very common. I try to check it one more time.