# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session, error-handling

I've been working on a web application with Symfony2 for the past 6 months on my local server through Xampp. After uploading it to our server something is acting really weird, and we can't seem to find a solution for the problem. After a lot of research on the internet I found that many problems are causing this error, so I started to try and debug my code. After a while I'm  not so sure that my code is causing the error.

The error I get is the following:

**Chrome:**

No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

**Firefox:**

Dutch error which probably sais; The connection was reset

**Safari:**

Safari can't open the page "domain" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.

The odd thing is that sometimes the page loads, but then after a couple of refreshes or trying a different time the same page gives the error? So it maybe has something to do with caching? I already disabled APC through the .htaccess file.

**Here are some things that might be usefull:**

Working with PHP Version 5.4.41.

OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2 (for what its worth)

Symfony 2

FOSUserbundle

FOSRoutingbundle

Ddeboerbundle

knplabsbundle

If you want I can upload my error log, but this doesn't seem to give any errors at all.

This is a discussion from earlier which said that changing the php version solved the problem. The problem might have been the sessions, but I tried the application with these sessions off and still got the error. We changed the php server to 5.4 on our local server but the application still worked. So I guess these are both not the problem.

[Symfony 2: session_start causes ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262958/symfony-2-session-start-causes-err-empty-response)

Does anyone have a solution for how to tackle this problem? Or maybe a suggestion on how to receive a more specific error? Because I'm killing my brain here.

Comment: Do you have `Apache` or `nginx` on your production server? If `Apache`, does your `PHP` run as a module or as CGI?

Comment: Hey there Jovan, we use Apache and we run our PHP as CGI.

Comment: Both in your dev environment as well as in production?

Comment: I'm using Xampp without CGI I guess, but another co worker uses Apache with CGI. (I'm just an intern)

Comment: Ah right, sorry, you said that above :) My first guess would be to check your production server's CGI configuration. Also, can you check your production's Apache's `error_log`?

Comment: We looked at our Apache's error log, nothing there. if u want, I can update my answer and post the error log in there? What is it I'm looking for at the CGI configuration?

Comment: Unrelated to CGI, check this SO question and answer about `xdebug`: http://serverfault.com/questions/458057/the-server-closed-the-connection-without-sending-any-data